# Declaring arrays with const variables

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multidimensional array, however when I pass a const int value I can't compile.  Error is "expression must have a constant value" for each dimension.

```
class Matrix {

 public:
     Matrix(int rowCount, int columnCount, int scalarInput) { 

        const int row_C = rowCount;
        const int colum_C = columnCount;
        const int scalar_C = scalarInput;

        matrixCalculation(row_C, colum_C, scalar_C);
    }


    void matrixCalculation(const int i, const int j, const int s) {

        int matrixArray[i][j]; // error here, i and j: "expression must have a constant value"


    }

};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array dimensions must be *compile-time constant*, and `const` doesn't mean that.

A `const` object cannot change its value after initialisation, but its initialiser may be determined at runtime (e.g. `const int x = rand()`) so, in general, these objects are not valid candidates for array dimensions.

Introducing... `constexpr`.

If you plonk the keyword `constexpr` in front of the dimensions, you will be off to a good start. Your compiler will prevent you from breaking the contract of `constexpr`, and will consequently enable you to use your shiny new `constexpr` object as an array dimension.

Alas, in this example, you *are* breaking that contract already, since the inputs are non-constant. Tough cookies.

**Use a vector instead.**

Comment: Though I would also recommend a vector, you can still use arrays, you just have to allocate them dynamically. int **MatrixArray = new int*[i]; for(int k = 0; k < i; k++) { MatrixArray[k] = new int[j]; } This works because the system can ask for more memory when it's the heap whenever you need it (during runtime), so you can allocate the 2D array on the heap. Arrays on the stack need to have constant values like @Lightness said. Again, a vector is easier, but this is basically what the vector is doing under the hood.

Comment: Seems like I will have to use vectors then, thanks for the speedy reply.